# MS Access working with multiple UNION statements

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables in MS Access: Anime, Film, and Series, all of which have name attributes (anm_name, flm_name, and srs_name) and genre attributes (anm_genre, flm_genre, and srs_genre) and I'm trying to include all of the name attributes that share the same genre value to a single column using UNION. I've succeeded in doing so with a single genre, this is the code I used:

```
SELECT 'Anime ' AS [Media Type], anm_name AS [Action] FROM Anime
WHERE anm_genre LIKE "*Action*"
UNION
SELECT 'Film ', flm_name AS [Action] FROM Film
WHERE flm_genre LIKE "*Action*"
UNION
SELECT 'Series ', srs_name AS [Action] FROM Series
WHERE srs_genre LIKE "*Action*";
```

but when I attempt to sort another one to a different column using the same code structure:

```
SELECT 'Anime ' AS [Media Type], anm_name AS [Action] FROM Anime
WHERE anm_genre LIKE "*Action*"
UNION
SELECT 'Film ', flm_name AS [Action] FROM Film
WHERE flm_genre LIKE "*Action*"
UNION
SELECT 'Series ', srs_name AS [Action] FROM Series
WHERE srs_genre LIKE "*Action*"

SELECT anm_name AS [Adventure] FROM Anime
WHERE anm_genre LIKE "*Adventure*"
UNION
SELECT flm_name AS [Adventure] FROM Film
WHERE flm_genre LIKE "*Adventure*"
UNION
SELECT srs_name As [Adventure] FROM Series
WHERE srs_genre LIKE "*Adventure*"
```

I get the following code error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqfTI.png)

This is a sample from my database: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/x4ETk)

An expected output would be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EbTO.png)

I want the name records from all three tables that correspond to, say for example, a genre record that has the value `Action` to be grouped in one single column that has the name 'Action', and the same with `Adventure` and so on.
My problem appears to be related with the fact that I'm using different Aliases of columns that already have Aliases.

Comment: Your current edit is missing a `UNION` here: `WHERE srs_genre LIKE "*Action*"

SELECT anm_name` and is using an unequal number of columns

Comment: I'm trying to create different columns for Action and Adventure, wouldn't doing what you suggest only squeeze them to a single one?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything. I'm noting that you have a syntax error (2 separate queries without a `UNION` between them, and an inequal number of columns between those queries).

Comment: So any *suggestions* as to who I might get the desired effect?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want, so I can do little more than point out syntax errors. If you provide sample data and an expected result based on that data, I can both answer your question and validate my answer.

Comment: This [is](https://i.imgur.com/xW09RRS.png) what I'm hoping my queries would achieve. After further research, I found that I can't use a column with different aliases, if you could provide me with a workaround to this I would be grateful.

Comment: Still not a clue. Provide both sample data from your tables, how that leads to the expected result (e.g. which data goes where and why) and expected result. Also, please edit it in your question, and share tables as outlined [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359204/7296893)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `FROM` statement in your second set of unions:

```
SELECT anm_name FROM Anime
WHERE anm_genre LIKE "*Adventure*"
UNION
SELECT flm_name AS [Adventure] FROM Film
WHERE flm_genre LIKE "*Adventure*"
UNION
SELECT srs_name As [Adventure] FROM Series
WHERE srs_genre LIKE "*Adventure*"`
```

Comment: That was short on my part, I omitted it when I was attempting to fix the code. The problem, however, still persists.

Comment: I believe you also need a semicolon after your first set of unions.

Comment: Nope, I get the error `Characters found after end of SQL statement`. I suppose it's worth to point out that I'm using MS-Access, maybe this differs across SQL platforms.

Answer (score 0):

There's a comma at the end of your SQL statement.

```
WHERE srs_genre LIKE "*Adventure*"`
```

should be

```
WHERE srs_genre LIKE "*Adventure*"
```

Comment: Sadly, that's not where the problem lies.

Comment: Well it does explain your original error, that's what you started your thread for so that issue is resolved now. If you run into new issues then you should post a new question.

Comment: That was a typo of the time I was writing this thread. The problem existed long before that and the thread describes it as such.

Comment: You stated "I get the following code error" including a screen dump of the error. So now you're saying you have a different problem? Pretty much confusing. I **strongly** suggest to start a new thread and indicate clearly what your actual issue is.

Comment: I've always had the same problem, that error comes up after I run my original code. As I said previously, the syntax mistake that you pointed out only came about after I started writing this thread, which I created to solve a problem that existed long before I created the thread, understood?